# implement __rmul__ from both sides, python

Tags: python, class, operators

I there a way to implement **rmul** so that it works in both directions?
I'm using **mul** to multiply two vectors a and b of class R3 element by element. Later I want to be able to multiply each element by a number with an operator like 2*a and a*2.

```
class R3(object):
    def __init__(self,an_array):
        self.a = an_array   # of length 3
        self.s = 3 

    def __mul__(self,that):
        tmp = [0]*self.s
        for i in range(self.s):
            tmp[i] = self.a[i]*that.a[i]
        return self.__class__(tmp)

    def __rmul__(self,that):
        tmp = [0]*self.s
        for i in range(self.s):
            tmp[i] = self.a[i]*that
        return self.__class__(tmp)
```

so this works fine for a * b, b * a, 2*a, but not a*2!

Comment: Just use numpy ndarrays.  They do this stuff already.

Comment: File "<ipython-input-8-656623baf1ec>", line 1, in <module>
    a*2

  File "C:/Users/Hossein/Documents/R3.py", line 16, in __mul__
    tmp[i] = self.a[i]*that.a[i]

AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'a'

Comment: @wim I know, this is just practice!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not implement `__rmul__` for both sides, because `__rmul__` is, by definition, for right multiplication.  When you want to change the behaviour of `x * y` you have to look at either `x.__class__.__mul__` or `y.__class__.__rmul__`.

- `a * b` uses `R3.__mul__` (OK)
- `b * a` also uses `R3.__mul__` (OK)
- `2 * a` first uses `int.__mul__`, fails, then tries `R3.__rmul__` instead (OK)
- `a * 2` uses `R3.__mul__`, fails, uses `int.__rmul__`, fails again (NOT OK!)

The way you have written it currently, `__mul__` assumes `that` argument is an `R3` instance, and `__rmul__` assumes `that` argument is a scalar.

You can not modify `int.__rmul__`, to change the behaviour of the last case, because you can't patch those built-in types.  However, you can modify your `R3.__mul__` to change that behaviour.

You've implemented `__mul__` to handle only `R3` instances passed into `that`.  Fix it so it can handle scalars passed into `that` aswell.

Comment: yes, when a comes first, __mul__ called. I'm wondering if there is way to make all of that OK. thanks for summarizing my question.

Comment: @hosseinsadeghi he **ANSWERED** your question.

Comment: @RickTeachey, yes the edit is the answer. The first draft was not!

Answer (score 0):

```
class NumString:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = str(value)

    def __str__(self):
         return self.value

    def __int__(self):
        return int(self.value)

    def __float__(self):
        return float(self.value)

    def __add__(self, other):
        if '.' in self.value:
            return float(self) + other
        return int(self) + other

    def __radd__(self, other):
        return self + other

    def __iadd__(self, other):
        self.value = self + other
        return self.value

    def __mu1__(self, other):
        if '.' in self.value:
            return float(self) * other
        return int(self) * other

    def __rmu1__(self, other):
        return self * value
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please edit your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.